# Getting value of checked box in array using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form which is formatted using a table the code is given below

```
echo'<form id="change_entry" name="change_entry" >';
echo"<div align='center' id='qtrpanel'>";
echo 'Please select Year and Quarter </br>';
    $dyear=2014;
    $thisyear=date('Y');
    $diff=$thisyear-$dyear;
echo '<select name="yeardate" id="yeardate">';
for ($i=$dyear;$i<=$thisyear;$i++){ echo'<option class="green" value="'.$i.'"'; 
            if ($thisyear==$i) {echo 'selected';}
            echo'>'.$i.'</option>'; }
        echo '</select>';

        echo "<td colspan='2'> <select name='qtr' id='qtr'> <option value=''>Select Quarter</option>
      <option value='I'>QTR-I</option> <option value='II'>QTR-II</option> <option value='III'>QTR-III</option> <option value='IV'>QTR-IV</option></select></div>";

       echo "<div id='tldlist' align='center'><table class='wqtable'><tr><th>TLD No</th><th>Location</th><th>Date of Removal</th><th>Dose Rate (mGy/h)</th><th>Lost</th></tr>";

                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($data))
                    { 
                    $rc++;
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' value='".$row['tldno']."'/></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['location']."</td>";

                    echo "<td><input type='text' id='datepicker".$rc. "'name='datepicker'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input size='5' id='dose".$rc."'  value='".$row2['radn_level']."'/></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='lost".$rc."'  value='Y'/></td>";

                    echo "</tr>";
                }

     echo " </table></div>";
     echo '<div align="center">';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" width="30" />';
     echo '</div>';

     echo '</form>';
```

The table gets some data from mysql table and remaining data is entered by user. I submit this data for update/insert to another php script using jquery post. The form data is obtained using following jQuery

```
jQuery('#change_entry').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var arr = jQuery('#change_entry tr:gt(0)').map(function () {
        return [jQuery('input', this).map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get()];
    }).get();

    var qtr = jQuery('#qtr').val();
    var yeardate = jQuery('#yeardate').val();

    jQuery.post("scripts/tld_change_entry.php", { "records": arr, "yr": yeardate, "qtr": qtr }, function (data) {

        jQuery('#tldlist').html(data);
    });
});
```

Now the problem is the last `<td>` contains a checkbox, whose default value is 'Y' and this value to be taken only if it is checked. But with my script, it is taking all instances of checkbox as 'Y'. I know how to check the checkbox status in jquery. But I do not know how to use it in .get() . Please suggest any method. I can replace the checkbox with a text input, but check box looks better that text input in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `if (this.type != "checkbox" || this.checked)` condition in your `map()` like following.

```
var arr = jQuery('#change_entry tr:gt(0)').map(function () {
    return [jQuery('input', this).map(function () {
        if (this.type != "checkbox" || this.checked) //added this line
            return this.value;
    }).get()];
}).get();
```

Comment: changed like this, working:::::return [jQuery('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get()];

Comment: It will cause problem if you use `input` `type` other than `text`, like `number`, `email` etc. @mansoondreamz

Answer (score 0):

Changing this part of the code..

```
return [jQuery('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).map(function() {
   return this.value;
}).get()];
```

Comment: Tried, still it is taking all checkbox values as 'Y'

Comment: changed like this, working:::::return [jQuery('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).map(function() {
   return this.value;

Comment: return [jQuery('input[type="text"],input[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).map(function() {
   return this.value;

Comment: So why don't you show mercy in accepting the right answer :)

Comment: the 'input' considers all input boxes, so it is not considering second input:checked. So I changed first input to input type=text this is same as what azim suggested @reddy

Comment: I checked Azim's answer. Yours is not working. I modified yours and posted in the comment. I am thankful to you for providing a thread . Do you want me to select your answer also as a correct one?

Comment: Nope, you can do it for only one answer. @Azim got this one.